# Is there possible to access a Realm DB Android from a different version of the project?

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I have a mobile Android native application using the Realm database to save some information. But now, I created a fully new version of my application using React Native **(but, the package name is the same to just replace in the google store)**.
My question is:
Can I access this data on the new application when the user upgrades the app?
I installed and tested Realm on the react-native project, but will I can access the old app data?

Thanks